# Downvoting a downvoted question of a 1 rep user

Tags: discussion

Is there a point to downvote a question from a user that has the minimum reputation score available and which question has already a negative score?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the same reason you'd downvote any question, for the downvote reason:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not
>   useful

Downvoting questions lets the OP and future visitors know that questions like that are not a good fit for the site in their current state.

I see downvoting questions as a way to show my opinion of the question. I don't think of it as a way to punish the user by taking away reputation. It doesn't matter if they have a lot of reputation or 1 reputation, **the downvote is for the question, not the user**.

Comment: This. It's a like / dislike button for me, not a reward / punish button.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do believe that haters will hate, so I'm sure there are a lot of "punishers" out there. That's what I think when I see questions with -5... "Ok, the op got the point now, get on with it.." There is no way to prevent that behaviour though.

Comment: Well yes, you asked for a reason. This is the legitimate reason. There are certainly those that abuse their power and anonymity, it's the internet after all.

Comment: I don't think a -5 necessarily indicates punishment. -1 means someone didn't like a question. It gives no indication of how the community actually feels on the question... it just shows the opinion of some person on the internet. A vote is your voice. Regardless of the vote count you should vote to make sure your voice is heard. If people follow this questions will get to -5 and lower.